# Run .wasm (WasmGC) files from the terminal or from code?

Tags: terminal, v8, webassembly

Is there a way of running .wasm files programmatically or through the terminal that allows running .wasm files that follow the WasmGC spec today?

Answer (score 0):

As of V8's 11.9 branch (shipped in Chrome 119 about a month ago), WasmGC is enabled by default, so you can run Wasm modules that use WasmGC features just like you would run any other Wasm module.

See also [webassembly.org/roadmap](https://webassembly.org/roadmap/) for the current status of new features in various browsers/runtimes.

Comment: I know this. As i write I want to execute the files in the terminal or some code and therefore not have to open chrome to do so. I have tried node.js without luck. I have used wasmtime in the past but it does not support WasmGC at the moment. I have not been able to get v8 cli to work either. This is why I hoped someone had a trick.  thank you for your answer.

Comment: @TroelsLund For terminal usage, you can either compile V8's `d8` shell yourself, or download it via [JSVU](https://github.com/GoogleChromeLabs/jsvu). Node will also work in the future, once they update to a sufficiently new V8 version. (Also, why did you tag this question `google-chrome` when a Chrome-related answer was specifically _not_ what you wanted?!)